# Servlet on one tomcat passing data to another servlet running another tomcat server?

Tags: servlets

Hi i want to know if its possible to have data being passed to another servlet running a different server (example Tomcat host port 9090) from a servlet running on tomcat server (host port 9999)?

Doing a project in java using NETBEANS.

I have searched around and tried some of the snippets of codes like HTTP Request and HTTP Connection but to no avail. Is this really possible? If yes, can anyone give me some explanation or hints what to search for in google? Im stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes I think it would be possible but I can't even begin to think of why you would want to do something like that. In the first server you would need to use a URLConnection to perform a HTTP request on the target server and then gather the response manually. This would all happen inside the doPost / doGet method of first server and is explained here: [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests). This would get messy very quickly.

If you want to do interprocess communication have a look at [web services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html) they provide a much cleaner communication system and even work across different languages quite well.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Yup i have read the link before i posted this, got me confused and frustrated as well. After thinking so much, the reason i wanted to do what i had posted earlier was just to test whether it is possible. 

The actual thing im suppose to do is a client servlet from port 9009 to make a JSON HttpRequest to web service client servlet port 9999.

I have read about all the request and response codes but i am confused how to start. 

My client servlet which is a web application will input an identity number which are suppose to communicate with the web service client
by JSON

Comment: Honestly, have a read of that web services link, you don't need a deep understanding of HTTP to use web services (but it can help). I don't currently have any JSON web services in use but I've got a few SOAP ones, I'm sure the process will be very similar. To use the web service just grab a WSDL file from the server (the WSDL describes the service being offered) and then let Maven automatically generate sources classes that provide access. Accessing the web service is then just like making a regular method call, the hard work is in the generated classes.

Comment: Its okay, i have already solve it. Thanks guys fr viewing. And thank god. Alhamdulillah.

Comment: Thanks wobblycogs for being the one to make the effort to answer my silly question. :)